# Problems Updating Susy Gem

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass, susy-sass

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to working with gems so pardon me if my understanding in the subject is off.

I already installed Susy 1.0.9 and was hoping to update it to Susy 2.0.

I tried `gem install susy --pre` and it successfully installed Susy 2.0 along with the required versions of SASS and Compass. Though when I do `gem list`, it still shows Susy 1.0.9 and the SASS Version was also not updated.

Any ideas on how to properly update Susy, SASS and Compass? TIA

Comment: 1) When you install new versions, old versions aren't automatically removed. Is `gem list` showing only the old version, and not also the new? 2) Installing Susy 2.0 won't automatically update Compass. If you are using Compass with 2.0, you should `gem install compass --pre` as well. 3) Are you using any type of gem version management, RVM, Bundler, or Gemfile?

Comment: 1) Yes, it only shows the old version of Susy despite having installed it. 3) I believe I installed RVM when I attempted to learn Rails but I don't really use it that much ( as far as I know ). Thank you for your response @EricMSuzanne

Comment: RVM and similar tools are used to create gem environments that are distinct from each other, so you could install a gem in one environment and have it un-available in another. I don't know if that could be related. Try `gem uninstall susy` then `gem list` and `gem install susy` (2.0 is out now, so you don't need "--pre"). Then `gem list` again, and paste the results of the entire process? Do you notice any errors at any step?

Comment: @Eric M Suzanne when i uninstalled susy, it says 'Successfully uninstalled susy-2.1.1' which is weird because in gem list, it shows that susy 1.0.9 is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It seems that if you add `sudo` when installing gems, it installs the gem on a different directory from the one used when you don't use `sudo`. I saw this when I did `sudo gem list` and it displayed different results from a normal `gem list` command.

To be able to add gems without sudo I just did `chown -R [current_user] [ruby_directory]`